# error-getwa_not_assigned in invoice printing program

Tags: abap, sap-erp

i am getting this error in a batch job. it indicate the error in following line:-
is it related to field symbol or field catalog ?

```
 IF gv_flgi EQ abap_true.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT 'COL_HEAD3A' OF STRUCTURE <fs_label> TO <fs_intra>.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT 'COL_HEAD3B' OF STRUCTURE <fs_label> TO <fs_inter>.
    <fs_intra> = <fs_inter>.
```

this last line i am getting error.
can you plz help me with this.

Comment: Field-symbol, of course. Always investigate ST22 dumps thoroughly. All the info is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of your field symbols is not assigned. You can check if the field symbol is assigned by

```
check <fs_myfieldsymbol> is ASSIGNED .
```